# Creating fur texture for Mid Poly Look on Model?

Tags: modeling, mesh, texturing

We are creating a animal model that has fur for a new game. We are creating it in Blender and will import it to Unity. We are going for an midpoly aesthetic similar to Breath of the Wild/Everwild We are trying to create a fur texture on the mesh but it keeps coming out odd and too pixelated. Can someone share an idea/technique to create a fur texture that might work. Thanks

[image]
[image]

Comment: hello, your question is a bit too vague, maybe show some reference pictures of what you're trying to achieve

Comment: Hi. This question was put on hold because as it stands it is not answerable for lack of essential details to understand the issue. Remember only you have access to your scene, so unless you describe it thoroughly only you know your exact setup, settings and what steps you took to arrive where your are now. Please describe in detail what your issue is, possibly supported by [some accompanying screenshots](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) with the [edit] button above. Don't post a comment or ask a new question, editing will automatically put it up for review so it can be reopened.